# Read String from specific folder in internal storage

Tags: java, internal-storage

I tried to read content from my file in internal storage with this code:

```
public String read_file(Context context, String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

//filename is "et1.txt"

but it returns "".
I also tried to use:

```
File fileDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Vara2/"+"et1"+".txt");
                File[]files=fileDirectory.listFiles();
                String string=files[0].toString();
```

But files array length is null.

I have permissions in my manifest file, for reading and writing external storage, and I call "request permission" in my activity.
My opinion is that error is in the path. My file "et1.txt" is in the internal storage, but in the folder "Vara2", so, I guess, access to the folder is the problem. 
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: are you getting any exceptions in catch blocks?

Comment: In the first case, there is no error, just an empty string.
In the second it says:
Attempt to read from null array

Comment: File fileDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Vara2/"+"et1"+".txt");
this is not a dir maybe you need to remote et1.txt

Comment: When I remove "+"et1"+".txt" ", there is no error, but how can I get string from file "et1.txt" ?